# Locale settings for RHEL 7/8

Tags: rhel, configuration, locale, localectl

In RHEL7/8 I know we control the locale setting using localctl command and which updates the /**etc/locale.conf** file.

Ex :

> ```
> # localectl set-locale LANG=ja_JP.utf8
> # localectl set-keymap jp106
> # localectl    System Locale: LANG=ja_JP.utf8
>        VC Keymap: jp106
>       X11 Layout: jp
> ```

But in RHEL6 we have another file for this purpose

**/etc/sysconfig/i18n**

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 
SUPPORTED="en_US.UTF8:en_US:en:ja_JP.eucXXXXX" 
SYSFONT="lat0-sun16"
SYSFONTACM="8859-15"
```

My question is do we need these variables also in RHEL7/8.

- SUPPORTED
- SYSFONT
- SYSFONTACM

My guess is we dont need to explicitly declare these variables anymore in RHEL7/8 ?

Answer (score 1):

1. I've never known or understood what `SUPPORTED` means and the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/ch-the_sysconfig_directory) is not clear at all: "A colon-separated list of supported languages". Supported by what and where? I guess you can omit it.
2. `SYSFONT` means "The default system font", this is now [configured via](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/vconsole.conf.html) `/etc/vconsole.conf` using the `FONT` variable.
3. `SYSFONTACM` has been [replaced](https://blog.fpmurphy.com/tag/sysconfig) with `FONT_MAP` in the same file.